# Order bars in a barplot in r

Tags: bar-chart

I already have the script of my analysis and graphic, but what should I switch to change the order of the bars? Sorry for my bad English.

```
dados<- read.table("anova2.txt",h=T)
dados
attach(dados)
analise<- aov(dados$germ~dados$trat, data=dados)
summary(analise)
tapply(dados3$germ,dados3$trat, mean)
mean<- tapply(dados2$germ,dados2$trat, mean)
se<- tapply(dados$germ,dados$trat, function (x) sd(x/sqrt(length(x))))
grafico<-barplot(mean, beside=T, names.arg=c("C", "EM", "EQ", "CT","AG"), 
xpd=F,ylim=c(0,100),
xlab="Tratamento", ylab="Taxa de Germinação (%)", cex.lab=1.3)
arrows(grafico, mean+se, grafico, mean, angle=90, code=1, length=0.1)
arrows(grafico, mean+se, grafico, mean-se, angle=90, code=3, length=0.1)
```

Comment: Have you tried re-ordering your data frame?

Comment: worked!!!! thanks!!